# Would companies be interested in seeing computer programs in a resume?

Tags: resume, job-search

I am still 18 and started college, and I want to be a back-end developer. I have a fairly decent knowledge of programming and have been programming for ~8 years, but I've never really put in the effort of finishing anything. Would it be smart to finish several different projects to put on a resume? Would recruiters be interested in actually looking at those projects? Thanks.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Yeah I work on lots of very broad projects (e.g. fully fledged game engines) and lose interest since I don't actually have any specific goals. Not smart. I'll try changing that and get some projects up on GitHub, whether that means to start with smaller goals in mind or make better plans.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Put them on GitHub and finish them up. Actual experience in delivering projects is worth a ton, even if those projects are just things you coded in your spare time. This applies to very much all levels of software developers, and if nothing else shows that you have passion for it.

Comment: This.  No one wants to see code on a resume.  Just about everyone is happy to see links to a github account that *contains* code on a resume.

Comment: Ok, so my plan is to get some ideas for projects and finish them over upcoming summers and post them on GitHub as I work on them. Thanks!

Comment: here, we agree!

Comment: @MCMastery doesn't even have to be finished, they rarely are, it's you showing what and how you create them is what matters.

Comment: Software is never finished, only released.

Comment: Please this. Seeing GitHub links on a resume makes me so happy. Even more so when you can walk me through your logic and decision making with the code.

Comment: I'd add that if the repos linked to in your resume are popular, that's more likely to get you hired.

Comment: We interviewed a Senior Java developer while also looking for Android developers. He listed Android in his CV while also providing the name of some apps he had developed. We looked for them on Google Play and ended up sending him an offer for the Android developer position.

Answer (score 2):

Recruiters are not very likely to be interested in any projects that you have done, though it may be worth it to mention it if they are seeking you out for a specific role in mind.  For example, if the role they are trying to fill is a database admin role, you may want to mention a project where you stood up a database and managed it.

As a hiring manager, I always look for GitHub or similar repositories.  If you're not on GitHub already, I would encourage you to create an account and upload your code.  This shows me where you are on your coding journey as well as you knowing how to use git.